# Change initial text color rendered in React CurrencyInput

Tags: reactjs

I want to change the initial color of the text in the CurrencyInput object.  Currently, I can control the text color only after having typed into the input.  The initial color at load is gray.  Once I start typing into the input, it is formatted in $aqua-blue (#29bbe3).

```
   <CurrencyInput 
       placeholder="$0.00" 
       type="text"
       value={this.state.salary}
       onChange ={this.onSalaryChange}
   />
```

Using this component:

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import MaskedInput from 'react-text-mask';
import createNumberMask from 'text-mask-addons/dist/createNumberMask';

const defaultMaskOptions = {
  prefix: '$',
  suffix: '',
  includeThousandsSeparator: true,
  thousandsSeparatorSymbol: ',',
  allowDecimal: true,
  decimalSymbol: '.',
  decimalLimit: 2, // how many digits allowed after the decimal
  integerLimit: 7, // limit length of integer numbers
  allowNegative: false,
  allowLeadingZeroes: false
}

const CurrencyInput = ({ maskOptions, ...inputProps }) => {
  const currencyMask = createNumberMask({
    ...defaultMaskOptions,
    ...maskOptions,
  })

  return <MaskedInput mask={currencyMask} {...inputProps} />
}

CurrencyInput.defaultProps = {
  inputMode: 'numeric',
  maskOptions: {},
}

CurrencyInput.propTypes = {
    inputmode: PropTypes.string,
    maskOptions: PropTypes.shape({
      prefix: PropTypes.string,
      suffix: PropTypes.string,
      includeThousandsSeparator: PropTypes.boolean,
      thousandsSeparatorSymbol: PropTypes.string,
      allowDecimal: PropTypes.boolean,
      decimalSymbol: PropTypes.string,
      decimalLimit: PropTypes.string,
      requireDecimal: PropTypes.boolean,
      allowNegative: PropTypes.boolean,
      allowLeadingZeroes: PropTypes.boolean,
      integerLimit: PropTypes.number,
  }),
}

export default CurrencyInput;
```

And using this css:

```
input {
    color: $aqua-blue;
  }
```

Appreciate any help.  Thanks

Comment: so initially does input have some default value ? and it color should be aqua blue before typing ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the placeholder text color like below

```
::placeholder { /* Chrome, Firefox, Opera, Safari 10.1+ */
  color: $aqua-blue;
  opacity: 1; /* Firefox */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `CurrencyInput` component, you should wrap it with a styled component like below and provide a prop saying what is the color. I guess you need to change the color depending on the `salary` value.

add `styled-components` npm package first,
in your `CurrencyInput`, do the following changes,

```
import styled from "styled-components";

const CurrencyInput = ({ maskOptions, inputColor, ...inputProps }) => {
  const currencyMask = createNumberMask({
    ...defaultMaskOptions,
    ...maskOptions,
  });

  const StyledCurrencyInput = styled.input`
    color: ${inputColor};
  `;

  return (
    <MaskedInput
      mask={currencyMask}
      {...inputProps}
      render={(ref, props) => <StyledCurrencyInput ref={ref} {...props} />}
    />
  );
};
```

In your component where `CurrencyInput` is used you can create a function like below to change the color depending on the `salary`,

```
resolveInputColor = () => {
   if(this.state.salary > 4000) {
      return 'red'
   }
   return 'blue' // default value
}

<CurrencyInput 
    placeholder="$0.00" 
    type="text"
    value={this.state.salary}
    onChange ={this.onSalaryChange}
    inputColor={this.resolveInputColor()}
/>
```

Hope this solves your intended problem!

Comment: @plivak, Check this out

Comment: Thanks Amila - I'm actually not trying to do anything conditional based on the amount of salary, just trying to make the input color aqua-blue when it first renders, but it is somehow gray and I can't see where that's being set.  Once the user begins to type numbers into the input, they are aqua blue.

Comment: @plivak, did you have a look here? https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_placeholder.asp